# lightgbm engine in tidymodels

Tags: r, tidymodels, r-parsnip

When I want to use the lightgbm engine for the boost_tree function in the parsnip package, I get an error like this:

```
lgbm_model <- 
  boost_tree( mode = "classification",
              mtry = tune(),
              trees = tune(),
              min_n = tune(),
              tree_depth = tune(),
              learn_rate = tune(),
              loss_reduction = tune(),
              engine = "lightgbm"
  )
```

error:

> Error in `check_spec_mode_engine_val()`:
> ! Engine 'lightgbm' is not supported for `boost_tree()`. See `show_engines('boost_tree')`.
> Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

What could this problem be related to?

Comment: The `bonsai` pacakge is required to use that model/engine combo. See the documentation at https://parsnip.tidymodels.org/reference/details_boost_tree_lightgbm.html. Make sure to install that package with `install.packages("bonsai")`

Answer (score -1):

The `show_engines('boost_tree')` shows the available engines for the model `boost_tree()`:

> engine  mode
>    
> 1 xgboost classification
> 2 xgboost regression
> 3 C5.0    classification
> 4 spark   classification
> 5 spark   regression

As we can see, there is no `lightgbm` engine here, therefore it cannot be used as an engine input.

The solution is adding the new engine to the `parsnip`. You can read about how to do so [here](https://www.tidymodels.org/learn/develop/models/)

Comment: For lightgbm, no need to manually create a new parsnip engine. See MrFlick's answer comment above.